# Sending a pic from an app with Action Send

Tags: java, android, image, share, shareactionprovider

I want to make an app with pics and make it possible to share one or some of these pics over whatsapp, gmail, mms whatever...
Half of the way I was able to code.

My problem now is I have one image in the app for testing(made with ImageView) pic is copied into drawable-hdpi.
If I have more pics what is the best way? (ImageView, Gallery,..?)
I want to store the pics inside of the app...

My SharedActionProvider is working I tested it with text.
I modified the code now to:

```
ShareActionProvider mShare = (ShareActionProvider) shareItem.getActionProvider();

    Intent picMessageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    picMessageIntent.setType("image/*");
    picMessageIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    picMessageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(imageView1));
    mShare.setShareIntent(picMessageIntent);
```

What I would like to know is:

How can I let the user decide which pic he wants to send?
The user marks it in the app then share to whatsapp for example?
Do I really need Uri?

I would be very happy if you could give me some help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is for me for the fullscreenactivity:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
        BitmapDrawable bm = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap mysharebmp = bm.getBitmap();


        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            mysharebmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

            //you can create a new file name "test.jpeg"
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                                    + File.separator + "tmp.jpeg");

            f.createNewFile();
            //write the bytes in file
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

            // remember close de FileOutput
            fo.close();
          Log.d("done","done");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
        sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/Pictures/tmp.jpeg"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
                            "Share image using"));

    }


}
```